# Angular CDK Drag & Drop - Snap to Grid

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am trying to use Angular's CDK Drag & Drop feature and its working great, however I can't find documentation on how to snap to a grid.

I found a GitHub issue that states that this feature has been added.

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15471

This is what I would like to achieve with the CDK's Drag & Drop.

https://xieziyu.github.io/angular2-draggable/#/advance/snap-grid

Comment: Hi, did you find something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `cdkDragConstrainPosition` input on your `cdkDrag` element

Example:

```html
<div cdkDrag [cdkDragConstrainPosition]="computeDragRenderPos">
  ...
</div>
```

```js
export class MyDraggableComponent {

  constructor() {}

  computeDragRenderPos(pos, dragRef) {
    return {x: Math.floor(pos.x / 30) * 30, y: pos.y}; // will render the element every 30 pixels horizontally
  }
}
```

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag 
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#DragRef